# php within html within php

Tags: php, html, template-tags

I use an extension called Custom Field Suite to import info from a csv in order to batch create posts. In order to display the form fields I use `<?php echo CFS()->get('image_location'); ?>` One type of information I import is image sources which I display images using `<img src="<?php echo CFS()->get('image_location'); ?>" class="preview" alt="image thumbnail" />` This works great without any problems.

But, I want the images to link to the next post using `next_post_link`. I've seen `<?php next_post_link('%link','<img src="IMAGELINK"/>'); ?>` but I can't quite figure out how to combine the two bits of php into a whole.

I've tried `<?php next_post_link('%link','<img src="echo CFS()->get('image_location')"/>'); ?>` but get a syntax error. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: You want the next post link to be an image?

Answer (score 2):

You can format it as, there's also no need to put the `echo`

```
<?php next_post_link('%link',"<img src=" . CFS()->get('image_location') . "/>"); ?>
```

`CFS()->get('image_location')` gets the field based on the current post id. If you want to use it for the next or previous, you have to pass the next or previous posts ID.

You can do something like this:

```
$next_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false, 'taxonomy_slug' );
$next_post_id = '';
if ( is_a( $next_post, 'WP_Post' ) )
    $next_post_id = $next_post->ID;
if ( ! empty( $next_post_id ) ) {
    $next_post_image_source = CFS()->get( 'image_location', $next_post_id );
} else {
    $next_post_image_source = "default image";
}

next_post_link('%link',"<img src=" . $next_post_image_source . "/>");
```

No assurance this would work but it should be easy to continue from here

Comment: That fixes the syntax error but the image is not displayed at all. It's not seeing the img src tag.

Comment: I've updated my code

Comment: It gets a syntax error on the `{` that comes before `$next_post_image_source = CFS()->get( 'image_location', $next_post_id );`. I've screwed around with it a bit but it keeps coming back to that `{`. Taking them out it errors on `$next_post_image_source`.

Comment: The problem was the `<?php` php tags in-between the code. My bad

Comment: Yep, I caught that. Should have mentioned that. Still has that same error.

Comment: And the closing `)` for the if clause `if ( ! empty( $next_post_id )`.

Comment: Something may be up with `next_post_link`. That fixed the error but put us back to square 1. The img src isn't displayed. I tried the generic `<?php next_post_link(); ?>` just to test that next_post_link is working but got the same result. Just to test I tried another template tag `posts_nav_link( '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', "<img src=" . CFS()->get('artwork_image_location') . ">" );` and the link to the next post worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the desired functionality using the `posts_nav_link` template tag. `posts_nav_link( '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', "<img src=" . CFS()->get('artwork_image_location') . ">" );` It looks like the `next_post_link` template tag is not working for me at all, even with a hard link to an image.